# closest approximation to finite dimensional subspace not unique

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I need to show that if $X$ is a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $A$ is a subspace dimension is finite, $x \in A^C$ then there is $a \in A$ such that  $d(x,A)= \lVert x-a\rVert$, and show that such that approximation in not unique.

I was able to prove the existence of the closet approximation $a$ but not sure how to prove the $a$ is not unique.

Comment: There are subspaces in which this approximation **is** unique, perhaps the point is to show that the approximation is not **necessarily** unique.

Comment: @BenGrossmann that is correct, i meant to prove the approximation is not necessarily unique by finding an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I note in my comment, there are normed spaces in which this minimizer is necessarily unique; for example, if $\|\cdot\|$ is induced by an inner product, then the minimizer will be unique for all subspaces $A$ and points $x \notin A$. With that in mind, it seems that the point of the question is to find an **example** of a normed space $X$, finite dimensional space $A$, and point $x \in A^C$ for which this approximation is not unique.

One such example is as follows. Take $X = \Bbb R^2$ with the norm
$$
\|(x_1,x_2)\|_\infty := \max\{|x_1|,|x_2|\},
$$
$A = \{(x,0): x \in \Bbb R\}$, and $x = (0,1)$. Show that the closest approximation to $x$ is not unique.

---

If you're interested in finding other examples, you might find it helpful to considering the following fact. The set of all minimizers is the intersection of the subspace $A$ and the the closed ball
$$
B = \{y \in X: \|x - y\| \leq d(x,A)\}.
$$
Using the definition of $d(x,A)$, we can conclude that the set $A \cap B$ will have an empty interior. Moreover, the set $A \cap B$ must be convex. Putting that together, perhaps you can see that in order for multiple minimizers to exist, $B$ must have a "flat boundary".